# Tree of StackExchange Sites

Tags: discussion, site-statistics

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157976/map-of-all-se-sites-except-the-3-biggest) really cool graph was posted onto meta.SO early December. Dunno how many over here have seen it... I thought it was super-fancy, so I'm sharing it here as well.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Already seen, but no prob posting here :)

Comment: Why are we next to islam?

Comment: @Bernhard No idea, but there are some alternate versions on the mother meta question Kitchi links to. Anyway, I think the colors denote pseudo-cliches of some kind so we may not be that related.

Comment: I take it back about the alternate versions. I must have been remembering a different post.

Comment: Errr... Sorry that I was late. But, we still have the same bubble design for our [Physics.SE tags](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1581) by Piotr Midgal - which is awesome too :-)

Comment: @Bernhard: Oh, that seems to be random. The colors tell you about grouping much more than the distances--the distances are calculated by Attractive-Repulsive Forces (ARF), but that doesn't mean that unrelated sites will always be far away.